# AjaxFileBrowser applet informations

Tags: applet, webdav, windows-server-2012, ithit-ajax-file-browser

I'm using ajaxfilebrowser on my webapp to browse a webdav folder for each user.
When i use the online update fonctionality, ItHit lunch an applet like this:

[image]

I want to remove the name and the editor of the applet and set my custom parameters.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This dialog provides information about the Java applet, so the user can clearly identify the vendor, name of the applet and where it comes from. It is displayed by the Java machine, you can not modify it freely.

However you can change the applet name and the publisher. To do this you will need to resign the applet with your own Java code signing certificate.